# PostgreSQL insert not working

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, heroku, insert

I'm trying to set up a simple database with Heroku/PGSQL. So far I've made a connection and created the table I want, but whenever I try and insert data to the table nothing happens.

For testing purposes, I'm using the code

```
$dbconn = pg_connect(pg_connection_string());
if (!$dbconn) {
   echo "Database connection error. ";
}
else {
// Create table
    $create="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
        gender CHAR(30), 
        age INT, 
        location CHAR(30), 
        timestamp CHAR(30)
        )";

// Execute query
    if (pg_query($dbconn,$create))  {
        echo "Table users created successfully. ";
    }
    else  {
        echo "Error creating table. ";
    }
}

function insert() {
    $dbconn = pg_connect(pg_connection_string());
    if (!$dbconn) {
        echo "Database connection error 2. ";
    }
    else {
        # Insert query
        $insert = "INSERT INTO users (id, gender, age, location, timestamp) VALUE (1234, 'male', 99, 'UK', '31/05/2013')";
        # Execute query
        if (pg_query($dbconn,$insert)) {
            echo "Data entered successfully. ";
        }
        else {
            echo "Data entry unsuccessful. ";
        }
    }

}
```

When run, it returns "Table users created successfully." However, when I call the `$$insert$$` function (I will later use this to insert different values into the table) it always returns unsuccessful.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO users (id, gender, age, location, timestamp)
VALUES (1234, 'male', 99, 'UK', '31/05/2013')";
```

maybe you shouldn't use char for timestamp

Comment: that was just an advice, the main error was VALUES like i posted

Comment: +1 It wasn't clear in your answer, but you saw and solved the mistake.

Comment: Thank you steven and eternay, you've no idea how silly I feel for missing that. I trawled other threads for examples and simply couldn't see it! Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

In the insert statement, VALUE should be VALUES.

Anyway, you should try to recover the error message given by database. I think it's possible in PHP. You'll have much more information about the reason of your error.